# Proving an upper bound of $\frac{4}3 \pi$ for a double-integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality

> Let $||\cdot ||$ denote the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose $f(x,y)$ has continuous partial derivatives on the unit disk $D = \{(x,y) : ||(x,y)||\leq 1\}.$ Suppose $f(x,y)=1$ on the boundary of $D$ and that $\max_{(x,y)\in D} ||\nabla f(x,y)|| = 1$, where $\nabla$ denotes the gradient. Prove that $|\iint_D f(x,y) dxdy | \leq \frac{4}3 \pi$.

Is the following true and if so, what exact theorem does it use (e.g. the Fundamental theorem of calculus or Leibniz's integral rule)? Could someone provide a justification or proof:

$f(0,0) - f(-1,0) = \int_{-1}^0 \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}f(t,0) dt\tag{*}.$

Fix $a,b \in D.$ Let $g : [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}, g(t) = f(bt+(1-t)a).$ Then $g$ is the composition of $f$ with $h$, where $h : \mathbb{R}\to D, h(t) = bt+(1-t)a$. Thus $g$ is differentiable with $g'(t) = \nabla f(bt+(1-t)a)\cdot (b-a),$ where $\cdot$ denotes the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $\max_{(x,y)\in D} ||\nabla f(x,y) || = 1$, by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, for all $t\in [0,1], |g'(t)| \leq ||\nabla f(bt+(1-t)a)||||b-a||\leq ||b-a||.$ Define for a subset $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2, k \in \mathbb{R}, kA := \{kx : x\in A\}.$ By the Mean Value Theorem, since $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, there exists $t\in [0,1]$ such that $f(b)-f(a) = g(1)-g(0) = g'(t).$

\begin{align}|\iint_D f(x,y) - f(\frac{x}2, \frac{y}2)dx dy| &\leq \iint_D |f(x,y) - f(\frac{x}2, \frac{y}2)| dxdy\\
&\leq \iint_D ||\nabla f(c)|| ||(x,y)-(\frac{x}2, \frac{y}2)||dxdy\quad \text{ (where $c\in \{tb + (1-t)a : t\in [0,1]\}$)}\\
&\leq \iint_D ||(\frac{x}2,\frac{y}2)||dxdy=\frac{1}2 \iint_{D}||(x,y)||dxdy.\end{align}

Thus $|\iint_D f(x,y)dxdy| \leq 4\iint_{D/2}1 dxdy\cdot \max_{(x,y)\in D/2}f(x,y) + \frac{1}2\iint_{D} ||(x,y)||dxdy.$

Similarly, we can show that for any $B\subseteq D, |\iint_B f(x,y) dx dy| \leq 4\iint_{B/2} 1 dx dy \cdot \max_{(x,y)\in B/2}f(x,y)+ \frac{1}2 \iint_{B} ||(x,y)||dxdy$.

So by induction, for any $n\ge 0, |\iint_D f(x,y) dx dy| \leq 4^{n+1} \iint_{D/2^{n+1}} 1 dxdy\cdot \max_{(x,y)\in D/2^{n+1}}f(x,y) + \sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{4^k}2 \iint_{D/2^k} ||(x,y)||dxdy)\tag{1}$

For any $r\in \mathbb{R}_{ > 0}, $  $\iint_{rD} f(x,y) dx dy = r^3 \iint_D f(x,y)dxdy \tag{2}$

Also, $\iint_D ||(x,y)|| dxdy = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 r^2 drd\theta = \frac{2\pi} 3,$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$

By $(2)$, $(1)$ is equivalent to $|\iint_D f(x,y) dx dy| \leq 4^{n+1} \iint_{D/2^{n+1}} 1 dxdy\cdot \max_{(x,y)\in D/2^{n+1}}f(x,y) + \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\pi}3 \frac{1}{2^k}\forall n\ge 0\tag{1'}$

Assuming $(*)$ holds and using the fact that $(-1,0)$ is on the boundary of $D$ gives $f(0,0)\leq 2$. Letting $n\to\infty$ on both sides of $(1')$ gives $|\iint_D f(x,y) dx dy|\leq \pi f(0,0) + \frac{2\pi}3 \leq \frac{8\pi}3,$ which clearly isn't good enough.

> Does anyone know how to get a better bound?

Comment: Side note: `\Vert` renders more nicely than `||` for norm signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given constraints suggest to estimate the value of $f$ at a point $(x, y)$ using the known value at the “nearest point” on the unit circle. With
$$
 g(t) = f(t \cos(\phi), t \sin(\phi))
$$
we have
$$
 g'(t) = \nabla f(t \cos(\phi), t \sin(\phi)) \cdot (\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi))
$$
and therefore
$$
 |g'(t)| \le \Vert \nabla f(t \cos(\phi), t \sin(\phi)) \Vert \le 1 \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
\bigl|f(r \cos(\phi), r \sin(\phi)) - f( \cos(\phi), t\sin(\phi)) \bigr| \le  1-r
$$
and therefore
$$
\bigl|f(r \cos(\phi), r \sin(\phi)) \bigr| \le 2 - r \, .
$$

Now use polar coordinates in $\left|\iint_D f(x,y) \, dxdy \right| $ to get the desired estimate.